# Magento 2.1.8 pdf href opening in a new tab

Tags: magento2, extensions, pdf

I am new in **Magento** and trying to modify an **extension**. I would like the **`href`** to open in a **new tab**. The code is as follows:

```
if ($itemRule['file_action'] == \Mageplaza\ProductAttachments\Model\Config\Source\FileAction::VIEWONLINE) {
    $href = $block->getUrl('mpattachments/file/viewonline', ['id' => $itemRule['file_id'], 'product_id' => $block->getProduct()->getId()]);
} else {
    $href = $block->getUrl('mpattachments/file/download', ['id' => $itemRule['file_id'], 'product_id' => $block->getProduct()->getId()]);
}
```

I Would highly appreciate some help.

Comment: could you share your whole code for this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $PdfName = $block->getProduct()->getName(); ?>
```

So:

**New tab:**

```
<a href="<?php echo $href; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $PdfName; ?></a>
```

**Download :**

```
<a href="<?php echo $href; ?>" download="<?php echo $PdfName; ?>"><?php echo $PdfName; ?></a>
```

Comment: thank you very much..I will see if that works and let you know.! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to add attribute `target="_blank"` in anchor tag in phtml file where this $href is echoing in href tag.
You can enable template hints to find which is this template actually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anchor() tag you can append a target attribute like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $href;?>" target="_blank" >View PDF</a>
```

If you have a button you can try as:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open(<?php echo $href;?>,'_blank')" />
```